# Change file name during Octopus Deploy

Tags: .net, octopus-deploy

I need to provide variable for different environments. For each environment I need to change names for certain files. What is best way to change names of certain files on Octopus Deploy? Is it possible with some existing Octopus functionality or I need to run PowerShell script for that purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no out of the box Octopus functionality to do this so you'd need to write some powershell. This could be a powershell deployment step, or a pre / post deploy script within your Nuget package step. These doco on [Powershell scripts here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/PowerShell+scripts).

You can also access the environment name from your script by looking at a [System Variable](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables), or if you like set a variable yourself and scope it to the environment.